# Alternative to Citrix Receiver

Tags: windows, vmware, citrix

We have an application deployed on a windows server. The application has a GUI that our business partners access by using Citrix Receiver. The way they access this GUI is by clicking an icon on Citrix Receiver Desktop App, which basically runs an exe file to give them this access. I am wondering if there is an alternative to Citrix so that users can still access the app in a similar way. We are not in a position to provide remote access to our app servers. Please advise and let me know if I need to provide any more details about this.

Comment: Hey there, I think there are better forums for questions like this. If the App is published by Citrix you need the Citrix Receiver / Citrix Workspace app. If you have a Citrix Virtual Desktop (VDI) you could configure on your Storefront the HTML5 option and launch it in the browser.

Comment: We deployed the app on shared drive so that users can access it via UNC path. Thanks @AzureBaum

Answer (score 0):

Answer out of my comment:

If the App is published by Citrix you need the Citrix Receiver / Citrix Workspace app. If you have a Citrix Virtual Desktop (VDI) you could configure on your Storefront the HTML5 option and launch it in the browser.

Greetings